# how to use a custom image instead of generated submit button

Tags: solspace-freeform

Freform PRO - 4.1.3
I'm using the tag {exp:freeform:form}

How do i reference my custom image instead of the generated button?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use the `{freeform:submit}` variable.

- You could use `<input type="submit" />` and style it with CSS to use a background image.
- Or use `<button type="submit"><img src="mybutton.png" /></button>`
- Or `<input type="image" src="mybutton.png" />`